# Does iOS image localization require the user to reinstall the app to see the proper images?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, ipad, localization

I've localized my images, but when I change the device language on the fly, the text changes but not the image. If I delete the app and then reinstall I can see the localized image.

Is this just how localization of images works? Or is there a way to make it so that the images change on the fly if the language does?

Answer (score 0):

My guess, based on behaviours I've observed with UIImages and the docs I've read:

When an image is first requested by the app, it's loaded and cached internally by UIImage. At first load, it's path is looked up in your app's resources. This will load the correctly localised image for your current language. This is then cached using some cache key.

I presume the cache key used by UIImage doesn't include the language, and so when you change the language of the phone UIImage still happily returns the cached image. Therefore, the app needs restarting before the newly localised images are loaded so that the resource path is discovered for the new language.

Remember this is conjecture based on my observations!